# Using Python to Create String Containing Descriptive Data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

From the below sample table I currently have the columns 'Lineup ID', 'Station', 'Affiliation', and 'Owner'. I want to create two additional columns, the first will be 'Duplicate Station', which shows the name of a station(s) with the same 'Lineup ID' and 'Affiliation', separated by a comma if there are multiple. I also remove the name of the original station in that row. Then I want to add a column 'Duplicate Owner', which will be the 'Owner' of the respective duplicate station(s). If there is no duplication of the 'Lineup ID' and 'Affiliation', it should show up as blank.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lineup ID':['1691', '1691', '1691', '1691', '1691', '1691'],
    'Station':['WRCB', 'WAAY', 'WXIA', 'WAFF', 'WTVC', 'WPXA'],
    'Affiliation':['NBC', 'NBC', 'NBC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ION'],
    'Owner':['Sarkes', 'Gray', 'Tegna', 'Allen', 'Sinclair', 'Scripps'],
})
```

Currently I'm doing this with the below:

```
s = df.groupby(['Lineup ID', 'Affiliation'])['Station'].agg(set)
o = df.groupby(['Lineup ID', 'Affiliation'])['Owner'].agg(set)
```

Then I rejoin with the original dataset, removing the original station:

```
df['Duplicate Station'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join(s[(x['Lineup ID'], x['Affiliation'])] - {x['Station']}), axis=1)

df['Duplicate Owner'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join(o[(x['Lineup ID'], x['Affiliation'])] - {x['Owner']}), axis=1)
```

print(df)

This results in something very close to what I want, except the Owners are misaligned with the stations. For example the row for WRCB will show:

```
Lineup ID Station Affiliation     Owner Duplicate Station Duplicate Owner
0      1691    WRCB         NBC    Sarkes        WAAY, WXIA     Gray, Tegna
1      1691    WAAY         NBC      Gray        WRCB, WXIA   Sarkes, Tegna
2      1691    WXIA         NBC     Tegna        WRCB, WAAY    Gray, Sarkes
3      1691    WAFF         ABC     Allen              WTVC        Sinclair
4      1691    WTVC         ABC  Sinclair              WAFF           Allen
5      1691    WPXA         ION   Scripps
```

I would like the Duplicate Owner to show in an order corresponding to the order of the Duplicate Station column. For WXIA, the Duplicate Owners are shown as 'Gray, Sarkes', but the stations are shown as 'WRCB, WAAY', so I'd like the 'Duplicate Owner' to show as 'Sarkes, Gray'. Is there a good way to dictate the order in which these values are aggregated?

Comment: Try to replace `agg(set)` by `agg('unique')`

Comment: `set`s are unordered data structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are unordered, which is why your aggregations don't line up. You can do the same thing using lists (which will retain order), although unfortunately it's harder to delete items from lists:

```py
def de_dupe(df, column):
    return [[v for v in a if v != b] for a, b in zip(df[f'{column}_Duplicate'], df[column])]

g = df.groupby(['Lineup ID', 'Affiliation'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)
res = df.merge(g, on=['Lineup ID', 'Affiliation'], suffixes=('', '_Duplicate'))
res['Station_Duplicate'] = de_dupe(res, 'Station')
res['Owner_Duplicate'] = de_dupe(res, 'Owner')
```

Output:

```
  Lineup ID Station Affiliation     Owner Station_Duplicate  Owner_Duplicate
0      1691    WRCB         NBC    Sarkes      [WAAY, WXIA]    [Gray, Tegna]
1      1691    WAAY         NBC      Gray      [WRCB, WXIA]  [Sarkes, Tegna]
2      1691    WXIA         NBC     Tegna      [WRCB, WAAY]   [Sarkes, Gray]
3      1691    WAFF         ABC     Allen            [WTVC]       [Sinclair]
4      1691    WTVC         ABC  Sinclair            [WAFF]          [Allen]
5      1691    WPXA         ION   Scripps                []               []
```

Note if you want comma separated string values, change the calls to `de_dupe` to e.g.

```
res['Station_Duplicate'] = list(map(', '.join, de_dupe(res, 'Station')))
```

or you modify `de_dupe` to include the `join`.

Comment: In a subsequent line I add the below to join these tables to the full dataset on lineup id and affiliation,, and remove the original station value, as I'm looking to include only the duplicate stations:

dupe_key['Dupe Station'] = dupe_key.apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join(d[(x['Lineup ID'], x['Affiliation'])] - {x['Station']}), axis=1)
dupe_key['Dupe Owner'] = dupe_key.apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join(s[(x['Lineup ID'], x['Affiliation'])] - {x['Owner']}), axis=1)

This is returning the below error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'set'

Comment: @Jpdiv no, that won't work with this approach. I think it would help a lot if you actually put some sample data and expected output into your question - for both parts of it. That will help you get a working answer.

Comment: Hey Nick, I added some sample data which hopefully provides a little more context. Thanks for any input.

Comment: @Jpdiv see my edit. I think it will do what you want.

Comment: thanks so much for the help, this worked perfectly, and thanks for providing the additional context to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `set` with `'unique'`. It should keep the order:

```
d = station.groupby(['Lineup ID', 'Affiliation'])['Station'].agg('unique')
s = station.groupby(['Lineup ID', 'Affiliation'])['Owner'].agg('unique')
```